# File not uploading in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to upload 3 files using html and PHP, in local server it is working but when I host it, this code is not working. What may be the problem?

Here is my HTML and PHP Code:

HTML CODE:

```
<form name="test" id="test" action="pet_up.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5097152" /> 
   Upload File 1:<input type='file' id='f1' name='f1'/>
   Upload File 2:<input type='file' id='f2' name='f2'/>
   Upload File 3:<input type='file' id='f3' name='f3'/>
  <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
if(isset($_FILES['f1']['name']))
{
$image1 = $_FILES['f1']['name']; 
$tmp1 = $_FILES['f1']['tmp_name']; 
$pathAndName1 = "uploads/".$image1;
if(!empty($_FILES) && file_exists($tmp1) && is_uploaded_file($tmp1)) 
{
    move_uploaded_file($tmp1,$pathAndName1);      
} 
else
{
    $pathAndName1="";
}
echo"<script>alert(".$pathAndName1.");</script>";
$qry="update petition set f1='".$pathAndName1."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
}


if(isset($_FILES['f2']['name']))
{
$image2 = $_FILES['f2']['name']; 
$tmp2 = $_FILES['f2']['tmp_name']; 
$pathAndName2 = "uploads/".$image2;
if(!empty($_FILES) && file_exists($tmp2) && is_uploaded_file($tmp2))
{
    move_uploaded_file($tmp2,$pathAndName2);      
} 
else
{
    $pathAndName2="";
}
echo"<script>alert(".$pathAndName2.");</script>";
$qry="update petition set f2='".$pathAndName2."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
}

if(isset($_FILES['f3']['name']))
{   
$image3 = $_FILES['f3']['name']; 
$tmp3 = $_FILES['f3']['tmp_name']; 
$pathAndName3 = "uploads/".$image3;
if(!empty($_FILES) && file_exists($tmp3) && is_uploaded_file($tmp3)) 
{
    move_uploaded_file($tmp3,$pathAndName3);      
} 
else
{
    $pathAndName3="";
}
echo"<script>alert(".$pathAndName3.");</script>";
$qry="update petition set f3='".$pathAndName3."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
}
```

Comment: We cannot say what the cause is if you don't tell us what error message / log file entry you get as a result on an upload attempt. We cannot _guess_ what the cause is, since there are many possible reasons.

Comment: Taking your comment to Nishants answer below it becomes clear that you hit some server limit. Might be upload size limit or the like, so a php setting most likely. We/you really need the error message in the log file, or you have to try around in a blind way. If you have no access to the log files, then you should find out the php limits in place, maybe by creating a test script using the famous `phpinfo()` function...

Comment: check **uploads** folder exists or not and waht is the permission of folder

Comment: @DeepakMane Look at the OPs comment to Nishants "answer" below: one file _is_ uploaded, so this is _not_ the problem. Yes, indeed, the OP should hae provided that information in the question.

Comment: I'd guess, that http posts are limited to a single file upload inside the php settings. But only you can tell what your limits are. You have to check that.

Comment: As you can see in the PHP code, I'm giving an alert to confirm whether  the file is uploading or not. the $pathAndName1, $pathAndName2, $pathAndName3 is setting to 'undefined'! When I submit the form atleast the file name should get read and the this file path sholud be stored in $pathAndName1, $pathAndName2, $pathAndName3. But it is not happening in this case...

Comment: @user3492308 Have you tried using my code?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, but it is going in infinite loop, and it is giving message as 'error in query' continuously...

Comment: @PrasadP.D. how can it go to the infinite loop... have you tried echoing `$count`.??

Answer (score 1):

by default, you can upload a file with 2Mb size, if you want bigger file to upload then change your php.ini file and set your value that you want to upload.

Comment: I think this is not the solution. Coz before I was trying to upload the files which were hardly 900KB, but problem was the same. And is it necessary to add:    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5097152" /> ??

Answer (score -1):

Please use this simplified version of your query.. This will help you debug more easily...

```
$count = count($_FILES);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
{
    if (isset($_FILES['f' . $i]['name']))
    {
        $image . $i= $_FILES['f' . $i]['name'];
        $tmp . $i= $_FILES['f' . $i]['tmp_name'];
        $pathAndName . $i= "uploads/" . $image . $i;
        if (!empty($_FILES) && file_exists($tmp . $count) && is_uploaded_file($tmp . $count))
        {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp . $i, $pathAndName . $i);
            echo 'error uploading file'.$i;
        }
        else
        {
            $pathAndName . $i= "";
        }
    }
    if ($pathAndName . $i!= '')
    {
        echo"<script>alert(" . $pathAndName . $i. ");</script>";
    }
    $qry = mysql_query("update petition set f" . $i. "='" . $pathAndName . $i. "'");
    if(!$qry)
    {
        echo 'error in query'.$i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Em, indeed this is _one_ possible cause, what makes you so sure this is the issue at hand? And why do you assume the OP has ftp access to that system and a specific application at hand? Also a permission of `777` _never_ is a good idea or really required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, while I was testing this code on server sometimes only one file got uploaded successfully out of 3 and sometimes no file got uploaded, So I think it is not the Permission issue...

Comment: Sorry, but posting an answer here should not be treated as a _guessing game_. Please try to find out what is the problem at hand and only _then_ post an answer. As you can see from the OPs comment your answer is simply wrong.

Comment: Sometimes guessing is necessary @arkascha

Comment: Absolutely, debugging is mostly guessing in the beginning, I agree. But such guesses are not answers! @Zword

Comment: @arkascha I am not god so I come to know all the answers.. We are here to provide suggestion.. if that wont work I will give another solution.. so downvoting without any reason, I dont think its a good choice of yours.. please consider helping others not finding mistakes of them..

Comment: @NishantSolanki 1. I _do_ try to help, read my comments above. 2. I did _not_ downvote without reason, I downvoted an answer that does not answer the question and 3. please read the guidelines for posting answers here. Thanks. If all wild guesses would be posted as "answers", then each and every question would have 20-30 "answers" and no one would understand anything. This is exactly what comments are there for. Why don't you use comments for such a guess?

Comment: @NishantSolanki Come on, be a good sport: instead of ranting against me you should consider if your answer really was such a good idea. Why don't you answer my question why you did not use the comments for this? We all know the answer I guess... And btw: why do you claim I do not help? Don't you see my comments to the OPs question? That is _not_ help? Be fair...